# Is there a way to avoid displaying help link in control panel using installshield for a basic msi project?

Tags: installshield-2012, control-panel

Is there a way to avoid displaying help link in control panel using installshield for a basic msi project?
I have a basic msi project. Help link that appears in Add/Remove programs of control panel needs to be removed. Other properties such as Support link,Update information needs to be retained.
Is there a way to remove Help link?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing is native Windows Installer functionality. You might ensure that the properties [`ARPHELPLINK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367587.aspx) and [`ARPHELPTELEPHONE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367588.aspx) are empty, to see if that provides the desired behavior. If not, I don't see any obvious way to influence this.